# SQL Exchange NULL with other row value on condition

Tags: sql, null, teradata, offset

I'm pretty new to SQL and I'm looking for a solution to a NULL values problem in a visw_feature_country and join_country columns.
Instead of NULL values I would like the cell to take non-null value from the nearest date (the same day, day prior or day after) for the same email.
I've attached the current result and the expected result screenshots.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE new_base_count AS
(SELECT COALESCE(visw.employeemail, vnotw.employeemail) AS visw_employeemail
,COALESCE(visw.completed_at, vnotw.completed_at) AS visw_completed_at
,CASE WHEN visw.feature_country IN ('UK', 'UK/IE', 'AU') THEN 'UK'
ELSE visw.feature_country END AS visw_feature_country
,CASE WHEN visw_feature_country IN ('UK', 'UK/IE', 'AU') THEN 'UK'
ELSE visw_feature_country END AS join_country
FROM new_visw visw

FULL OUTER JOIN new_vnotw vnotw
ON visw.employeemail = vnotw.employeemail AND
visw.completed_at = vnotw.completed_at 
AND visw.feature_country = vnotw.feature_country
FULL OUTER JOIN new_vwonly vwo
ON (visw.employeemail = vwo.employee_email OR vnotw.employeemail = vwo.employee_email)
AND (visw.completed_at = vwo.completed_at OR vnotw.completed_at = vwo.completed_at)
AND (visw.feature_country = vwo.feature_country OR vnotw.feature_country = vwo.feature_country)
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4) WITH DATA ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Current result:

[current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzS3H.jpg)

Expected result:

[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyaDV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try LAST_VALUE:

```
last_value(CASE WHEN visw.feature_country IN ('UK', 'UK/IE', 'AU') 
                THEN 'UK'
                ELSE visw.feature_country
           END IGNORE NULLS
over (partition by visw_employeemail
      order by visw_completed_at) AS visw_feature_country
```

Similar for join_country